# Java: convert a byte array to a hex string?

Tags: java, arrays, hex

I have a byte array filled with hex numbers and printing it the easy way is pretty pointless because there are many unprintable elements. What I need is the exact hexcode in the form of: `3a5f771c`

Comment: Why not just give it a try first and show us what you've got. You've nothing to lose and all to gain. Integer has a `toHexString(...)` method that may help if this is what you're looking for. Also `String.format(...)` can do some neat formatting tricks using the `%2x` code string.

Comment: possible duplicate of [In Java, how do I convert a byte array to a string of hex digits while keeping leading zeros?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/332079/in-java-how-do-i-convert-a-byte-array-to-a-string-of-hex-digits-while-keeping-l)

Comment: With the help of stream in Java 8, it can be simply implemented as:
static String byteArrayToHex(byte[] a) {
        return IntStream.range(0, a.length)
                .mapToObj(i -> String.format("%02x", a[i]))
                .reduce((acc, v) -> acc + " " + v)
                .get();
    }

Comment: Java 17 to the rescue: `HexFormat.of().formatHex(bytes)`

Comment: @tibetty You really call that "simple"?

Answer (score 1067, accepted):

From the discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/332079/1284661), and especially [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2197650/1284661) answer, this is the function I currently use:

```
private static final char[] HEX_ARRAY = "0123456789ABCDEF".toCharArray();
public static String bytesToHex(byte[] bytes) {
    char[] hexChars = new char[bytes.length * 2];
    for (int j = 0; j < bytes.length; j++) {
        int v = bytes[j] & 0xFF;
        hexChars[j * 2] = HEX_ARRAY[v >>> 4];
        hexChars[j * 2 + 1] = HEX_ARRAY[v & 0x0F];
    }
    return new String(hexChars);
}
```

My own tiny benchmarks (a million bytes a thousand times, 256 bytes 10 million times) showed it to be much faster than any other alternative, about half the time on long arrays.  Compared to the answer I took it from, switching to bitwise ops --- as suggested in the discussion --- cut about 20% off of the time for long arrays. (Edit: When I say it's faster than the alternatives, I mean the alternative code offered in the discussions. Performance is equivalent to Commons Codec, which uses very similar code.)

2k20 version, with respect to Java 9 compact strings:

```
private static final byte[] HEX_ARRAY = "0123456789ABCDEF".getBytes(StandardCharsets.US_ASCII);
public static String bytesToHex(byte[] bytes) {
    byte[] hexChars = new byte[bytes.length * 2];
    for (int j = 0; j < bytes.length; j++) {
        int v = bytes[j] & 0xFF;
        hexChars[j * 2] = HEX_ARRAY[v >>> 4];
        hexChars[j * 2 + 1] = HEX_ARRAY[v & 0x0F];
    }
    return new String(hexChars, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
}
```

Comment: I just found [javax.xml.bind.DataTypeConverter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/DatatypeConverter.html), part of the standard distribution.  Why doesn't this come up when you Google this kind of problem? Lots helpful tools, including `String printHexBinary(byte[])` and `byte[] parseHexBinary(String)`.  `printHexBinary` is, however, much (2x) slower than the function in this answer. (I checked the source; it uses a `stringBuilder`. `parseHexBinary` uses an array.) Really, though, for most purposes it's fast enough and you probably already have it.

Comment: +1 for the answer since Android does not have DataTypeConverter

Comment: @maybeWeCouldStealAVan: JDK 7 is now open source.  We should submit a patch to improve performance for `printHexBinary`?

Comment: @maybeWeCouldStealAVan could you please explain how this works. I follow for the most part but really like understanding what is happening when using code. Thanks!

Comment: This code is super-fast!! I was using `String.format("%0" + (bytes.length << 1) + "X", new BigInteger(1, bytes));` but the performance was rubbish. This is a much better solution.

Comment: How to to reverse i.e. Given a Hex String get byte[] from the String ?

Comment: @Whome Hmm, how are you benchmarking it? In my benchmarks the speed looks exactly the same, which makes sense since each has the same number of array index lookups and the same number of operations.  What advantage do you get from the larger table?

Comment: Great answer! A negligible performance increase could be obtained by adding a variable for `n * 2` to be used in the first array index, then `++n` in the second access.

Comment: This solution is better than DataTypeConverter solution because it uses StringBuilder which inturn uses char[] and expand.If we know the size beforehand I feel char[] is a superior option

Comment: Is this code working for negative byte value? bcz I'm getting a value which is out of range for byte, when byte value is negative.

Comment: `javax.xml.bind.DataTypeConverter` is being removed from Java 11.

Comment: Why is `& 0xFF` required in this line `int v = bytes[j] & 0xFF;`? Am I missing something or is it just unnecessary?

Comment: @AlbAtNf Java only has signed number primitives, so a byte that you imagine as 0xFF will be thought of as negative. An array index is always int, and just using the byte variable as an index position will do the same as the method does by assigning it to `int v`: The negative byte will be expanded - the int will be full of set bits. You'd not be asking for array index 15 but something in the millions.

Comment: Sometimes you need spaces, then use `bytes.length * 3`, `hexChars[j * 3]`, `hexChars[j * 3 + 1]` and `hexChars[j * 3 + 2] = 0x20`

Comment: @Gauss did your spacing suggestion, got error: `java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: " 16 BF 0C 13 C7 "`

Comment: @Starwave well I just did bytesToHex(new byte[] {0x16,0x0C,0x13}) and it works fine. 0xBF and 0xC7 are not bytes. They are ints.

Comment: Should check empty bytes: 
if (bytes == null || bytes.length == 0) return ""; to make sure no crash

Comment: Any benchmark does have more weight when done using jmh - https://github.com/openjdk/jmh If you have such benchmarks, please provide it here.

Comment: @maybeWeCouldStealAVan Thank you for your answer, it helped me a lot. I've slightly improved your solution in terms of performance by removing multiplications. The essential lines read like this:
`char[] hexChars = new char[bytes.length << 1];
     for (int j=0, k=0; j<bytes.length; ) {
         int v=bytes[j++] & 0xFF;
         hexChars[k++] = HEX_ARRAY[v >>> 4];
         hexChars[k++] = HEX_ARRAY[v & 0x0F];
     }
     return new String(hexChars);`
According to my simple tests, the improvement is in the range of 5 to 25 percent.

Comment: @Tillmann Interesting. When I wrote this (10 years ago, in Java 7 I believe) there was no speedup in using a shift in place of *2, so for legibility I wrote * when I was multiplying and >>> when I was extracting bits.

Answer (score 536):

The [Apache Commons Codec](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-codec/) library has a [Hex](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-codec/apidocs/org/apache/commons/codec/binary/Hex.html) class for doing just this type of work.

```
import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Hex;

String foo = "I am a string";
byte[] bytes = foo.getBytes();
System.out.println( Hex.encodeHexString( bytes ) );
```

Comment: @cytinus - My downvote occurred 4 months ago so I'm not entirely certain what I was thinking, but I was probably objecting to the size of the library. This is a small function within the program; there's no need to add such a bulky library to the project to perform it.

Comment: @ArtOfWarefare I agree, so instead of `import org.apache.commons.codec.*;` you could do `import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Hex;`

Comment: @ArtOfWarfare I have to disagree. The only terrible thing is that the apache commons libraries aren't included by default with the JRE and JDK. There are some libraries that are so useful they really should be on your class path by default, and this is one of them.

Comment: I highly recommend this answer is swapped as the top answer. Always vote to use a well tested, performant, open source library over custom code which doesn't improve on it.

Comment: When using sbt or maven, adding an open-source dependency like this is dead-easy.

Comment: Also, `commons-codec-1.9.jar` is 258 KiB, and I guess the space impact can go further down if you are going to use Proguard or something like this.

Comment: Not to reinvigorate an old thread spuriously, but as added documentation for future reference: even working for some very large and particular companies, the Apache license was deemed acceptable for use in our commercial products.  IMHO if you can't quickly drop in/manage 3rd party dependencies in your project for cases such as this, then you are not moving fast enough.

Comment: +1 for suggesting an off-the-shelf library - Just to point out - this method returns a char[] array rather than a string, which tripped me up for a bit. (and the method appears now to 'encodeHex' rather than 'encodeHexString' - could be just the version I'm using though).

Comment: At the time I wrote that, there were methods for encodeHex and encodeHexString, though that might be different now.

Comment: Or in case you use BouncyCastle (_org.bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk15on_), you can use this class : `org.bouncycastle.util.encoders.Hex`, with this method : `String toHexString(byte[] data)`

Comment: Inside `encodeHex`, this below part of the code is fishy. Is it correct to use `0xF0` here?...

```
for (int i = 0, j = 0; i < l; i++) {
            out[j++] = toDigits[(0xF0 & data[i]) >>> 4];
            out[j++] = toDigits[0x0F & data[i]];
        }
```

Comment: and you get all the security flaws from bouncycastle. Do not use a library for such basic operations

Answer (score 351):

The method [**`javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter.printHexBinary()`**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/DatatypeConverter.html#printHexBinary-byte:A-), part of the [Java Architecture for XML Binding (JAXB)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Architecture_for_XML_Binding), was a convenient way to convert a `byte[]` to a hex string. The [`DatatypeConverter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/DatatypeConverter.html) class also included many other useful data-manipulation methods.

In Java 8 and earlier, JAXB was part of the Java standard library. It was **[deprecated](https://cr.openjdk.java.net/~iris/se/9/java-se-9-fr-spec/#APIs-proposed-for-removal) with Java 9 and [removed](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/320) with Java 11**, as part of an effort to move all Java EE packages into their own libraries. [It's a long story](https://www.jesperdj.com/2018/09/30/jaxb-on-java-9-10-11-and-beyond/). Now, `javax.xml.bind` doesn't exist, and if you want to use JAXB, which contains `DatatypeConverter`, you'll need to install the [JAXB API](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.xml.bind/jaxb-api/2.4.0-b180830.0359) and [JAXB Runtime](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish.jaxb/jaxb-runtime/2.4.0-b180830.0438) from Maven.

Example usage:

```
byte bytes[] = {(byte)0, (byte)0, (byte)134, (byte)0, (byte)61};
String hex = javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter.printHexBinary(bytes);
```

Will result in:

```
000086003D
```

This answer the same as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14552724).

Comment: A good solution, though sadly not one that is valid in Android.

Comment: @Kazriko maybe you want to read https://code.google.com/p/dalvik/wiki/JavaxPackages. It is a way to get javax classes into Android. But if you only want convert to hex, it isn't worth the trouble.

Comment: Any there any comments on the performance vs. the accepted answer. This is obviously much simpler.

Comment: Win7-iCore5-430M-JDK1.7.0_11: 60 bytes input, 100000 loops -> accepted MaybeWeCouldStealAva answer=90ms. DatatypeConverter.printHexBinary=190ms.

Comment: DatatypeConverter is no longer accessible as of JDK 9

Comment: @pmcollins Why do you said it? At least in API docs, it's still there: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/DatatypeConverter.html

Comment: @PhoneixS It is still there, but not part of the default runtime (due to Java 9 modules).

Comment: don't rely on javax.xml.bind, it compiles fine but can be not be found at runtime. if you do, be prepared to handle  java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError

Comment: A proper solution inside a Java EE project with Jaxb provided.

Answer (score 291):

Simplest solution, no external libs, no digits constants:

```
public static String byteArrayToHex(byte[] a) {
   StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(a.length * 2);
   for(byte b: a)
      sb.append(String.format("%02x", b));
   return sb.toString();
}
```

Comment: This is very slow, on average 1000 times slower (for 162 bytes long) than the one in the top response. Avoid using String.Format if performance matters.

Comment: Maybe slow. It's good for things happening occasionally, such as login or similar.

Comment: Not "maybe slow", but very very inefficient. If you want to use slow code, at least reuse (not copy+paste) some of an existing library that has a test suite.

Comment: If it's slow, so what? In my use case it's just for a debug statement, so thanks for this code fragment.

Comment: Reusing a library by including an extra JAR files of several dozens kB would not exactly be efficient if all you need is this function (on some platforms like Android, the whole Jar gets included in the end application). And sometimes shorter and more clear code is better when performance is not needed.

Comment: @personne3000 maybe, but in that case you need stream support, not a single call feature. this one is easy to understand and remember, and therefore to maintain.

Comment: Creating a new java.util.Formatter for every single byte is not good for performance.  It’s better to create a single Formatter (note that `new Formatter()` automatically wraps a new StringBuilder internally), and call its `format` method in the loop.

Comment: how did you come up with that "1000 times slower"?

Answer (score 191):

Here are some common options ordered from simple (one-liner) to complex (huge library). If you are interested in performance, see the micro benchmarks below.

### Option 1: Code snippet - Simple (only using JDK/Android)

#### Option 1a: BigInteger

One very simple solution is to use the `BigInteger`'s hex representation:

```java
new BigInteger(1, someByteArray).toString(16);
```

Note that since this handles *numbers* not arbitrary *byte-strings* it will omit leading zeros - this may or may not be what you want (e.g. `000AE3` vs `0AE3` for a 3 byte input). This is also very slow, about *100x slower* compared to option 2.

#### Option 1b: String.format()

Using the `%X` placeholder, [`String.format()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html) is able to encode most primitive types (`short`, `int`, `long`) to hex:

```java
String.format("%X", ByteBuffer.wrap(eightByteArray).getLong());
```

#### Option 1c: Integer/Long (only 4/8 Byte Arrays)

If you **exclusively have 4 bytes arrays** you can use the [`toHexString`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#toHexString-int-) method of the Integer class:

```java
Integer.toHexString(ByteBuffer.wrap(fourByteArray).getInt());
```

The same works with **8 byte arrays** and [`Long`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Long.html#toHexString-long-)

```java
Long.toHexString(ByteBuffer.wrap(eightByteArray).getLong());
```

#### Option 1d: JDK17+ HexFormat

Finally, JDK 17 offers first-level support of straight forward hex encoding with [`HexFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/HexFormat.html):

```java
HexFormat hex = HexFormat.of();
hex.formatHex(someByteArray)
```

### Option 2: Code snippet - Advanced

Here is a full-featured, copy & pasteable code snippet supporting **upper/lowercase** and [**endianness**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness). It is optimized to minimize memory complexity and maximize performance and should be compatible with all modern Java versions (5+).

```java
private static final char[] LOOKUP_TABLE_LOWER = new char[]{0x30, 0x31, 0x32, 0x33, 0x34, 0x35, 0x36, 0x37, 0x38, 0x39, 0x61, 0x62, 0x63, 0x64, 0x65, 0x66};
private static final char[] LOOKUP_TABLE_UPPER = new char[]{0x30, 0x31, 0x32, 0x33, 0x34, 0x35, 0x36, 0x37, 0x38, 0x39, 0x41, 0x42, 0x43, 0x44, 0x45, 0x46};
        
public static String encode(byte[] byteArray, boolean upperCase, ByteOrder byteOrder) {

    // our output size will be exactly 2x byte-array length
    final char[] buffer = new char[byteArray.length * 2];

    // choose lower or uppercase lookup table
    final char[] lookup = upperCase ? LOOKUP_TABLE_UPPER : LOOKUP_TABLE_LOWER;

    int index;
    for (int i = 0; i < byteArray.length; i++) {
        // for little endian we count from last to first
        index = (byteOrder == ByteOrder.BIG_ENDIAN) ? i : byteArray.length - i - 1;
        
        // extract the upper 4 bit and look up char (0-A)
        buffer[i << 1] = lookup[(byteArray[index] >> 4) & 0xF];
        // extract the lower 4 bit and look up char (0-A)
        buffer[(i << 1) + 1] = lookup[(byteArray[index] & 0xF)];
    }
    return new String(buffer);
}

public static String encode(byte[] byteArray) {
    return encode(byteArray, false, ByteOrder.BIG_ENDIAN);
}
```

The full source code with Apache v2 license and decoder can be found [here](https://github.com/patrickfav/bytes-java).

### Option 3: Using a small optimized library: bytes-java

While working on my previous project, I created this little toolkit for working with bytes in Java. It has no external dependencies and is compatible with Java 7+. It includes, among others, a very fast and well tested HEX en/decoder:

```java
import at.favre.lib.bytes.Bytes;
...
Bytes.wrap(someByteArray).encodeHex()
```

You can check it out on [GitHub: bytes-java](https://github.com/patrickfav/bytes-java).

### Option 4: Apache Commons Codec

Of course there is the good 'ol [commons codecs](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-codec/). (***warning opinion ahead***) *While working on the project outlined above I analyzed the code and was quite disappointed; a lot of duplicate unorganized code, obsolete and exotic codecs probably only useful for very few and quite overengineered and slow implementations of popular codecs (specifically Base64). I therefore would make an informed decision if you want to use it or an alternative.* Anyways, if you still want to use it, here is a code snippet:

```java
import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Hex;
...
Hex.encodeHexString(someByteArray));
```

### Option 5: Google Guava

More often than not you already have [Guava](https://guava.dev/releases/16.0/api/docs/com/google/common/io/BaseEncoding.html) as a dependency. If so just use:

```java
import com.google.common.io.BaseEncoding;
...
BaseEncoding.base16().lowerCase().encode(someByteArray);
```

### Option 6: Spring Security

If you use the [Spring framework](https://spring.io/) with [Spring Security](https://spring.io/projects/spring-security) you can use the following:

```java
import org.springframework.security.crypto.codec.Hex
...
new String(Hex.encode(someByteArray));
```

### Option 7: Bouncy Castle

If you already use the security framework [Bouncy Castle](https://www.bouncycastle.org/) you can use its `Hex` util:

```java
import org.bouncycastle.util.encoders.Hex;
...
Hex.toHexString(someByteArray);
```

### Not Really Option 8: Java 9+ Compatibility or 'Do Not Use JAXBs javax/xml/bind/DatatypeConverter'

In previous Java (8 and below) versions the Java code for JAXB was included as runtime dependency. Since Java 9 and [Jigsaw modularisation](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/jigsaw/doc/jdk-modularization-tips) your code cannot access other code outside of its module without explicit declaration. So be aware if you get an exception like:

```java
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/JAXBException
```

when running on a JVM with Java 9+. If so then switch implementations to any of the alternatives above. See also this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43574426/774398).

---

## Micro Benchmarks

Here are results from a simple [JMH](https://openjdk.java.net/projects/code-tools/jmh/) micro benchmark encoding *byte arrays of different sizes*. The values are operations per second, so ***higher is better.***
Note that micro benchmarks very often do not represent real world behavior, so take these results with a grain of salt.

```
| Name (ops/s)         |    16 byte |    32 byte |  128 byte | 0.95 MB |
|----------------------|-----------:|-----------:|----------:|--------:|
| Opt1: BigInteger     |  2,088,514 |  1,008,357 |   133,665 |       4 |
| Opt2/3: Bytes Lib    | 20,423,170 | 16,049,841 | 6,685,522 |     825 |
| Opt4: Apache Commons | 17,503,857 | 12,382,018 | 4,319,898 |     529 |
| Opt5: Guava          | 10,177,925 |  6,937,833 | 2,094,658 |     257 |
| Opt6: Spring         | 18,704,986 | 13,643,374 | 4,904,805 |     601 |
| Opt7: BC             |  7,501,666 |  3,674,422 | 1,077,236 |     152 |
| Opt8: JAX-B          | 13,497,736 |  8,312,834 | 2,590,940 |     346 |
```

Specs: JDK 8u202, i7-7700K, Win10, 24 GB Ram. See the full benchmark [here](https://github.com/patrickfav/bytes-java/blob/master/src/test/java/at/favre/lib/bytes/EncodingHexJmhBenchmark.java).

### Benchmark Update 2022

Here are results with current JMH 1.36, Java 17 and a higher end computer

```
| Name (ops/s)         |    16 byte |    32 byte |  128 byte | 0.95 MB |
|----------------------|-----------:|-----------:|----------:|--------:|
| Opt1a: BigInteger    |  2,941,403 |  1,389,448 |   242,096 |       5 |
| Opt1d: HexFormat     | 32,635,184 | 20,262,332 | 7,388,135 |     922 |
| Opt2/3: Bytes Lib    | 31,724,981 | 22,786,906 | 6,197,028 |     930 |
```

Specs: JDK temurin 17.0.6, Ryzen 5900X, Win11, 24 GB DDR4 Ram

Comment: Quite thorough! Since you're using Java 17, you might want to add `HexFormat.of` to the options for people using `JDK17+`.

Comment: Was not aware of that, thanks for the hint - will update the answer!

Comment: @Patrick Would you please let the `HexFormat` kick into the Benchmark?

Answer (score 65):

A Guava solution, for completeness:

```
import com.google.common.io.BaseEncoding;
...
byte[] bytes = "Hello world".getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
final String hex = BaseEncoding.base16().lowerCase().encode(bytes);
```

Now `hex` is `"48656c6c6f20776f726c64"`.

Comment: In Guava you can also use `new HashCode(bytes).toString()`.

Comment: As of Guava 22.0 it is `HashCode.fromBytes(checksum).toString()`

Answer (score 47):

This simple oneliner works for me
    `String result = new BigInteger(1, inputBytes).toString(16);`  
EDIT - Using this will remove the leading zeros, but hey worked for my use-case. Thanks @Voicu for pointing it out

Comment: This _oneliner_ drops leading zero bytes.

Comment: @Voicu ... And it will add a leading zero 50% of the time.

Answer (score 42):

Java 17 finally contains [HexFormat](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/HexFormat.html) class so you can simply do:

```java
HexFormat.of().formatHex(bytes);
```

It supports configuration as lowercase/uppercase, delimiters, prefix, suffix etc.

Comment: Finally, something that doesn't need an external library or is a broken solution

Answer (score 29):

I would use something like this for fixed length, like hashes:

```
md5sum = String.format("%032x", new BigInteger(1, md.digest()));
```

Comment: Thank you, this is so pithy and appropriate.

Answer (score 24):

Use DataTypeConverter class`javax.xml.bind.DataTypeConverter`

`String hexString = DatatypeConverter.printHexBinary(bytes[] raw);`

Comment: Class removed in Java 11. See: [*JEP 320: Remove the Java EE and CORBA Modules*](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/320)

Answer (score 22):

I found three different ways here:
http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0596.html

The most elegant one, as he also notes, I think is this one:

```
static final String HEXES = "0123456789ABCDEF";
public static String getHex( byte [] raw ) {
    if ( raw == null ) {
        return null;
    }
    final StringBuilder hex = new StringBuilder( 2 * raw.length );
    for ( final byte b : raw ) {
        hex.append(HEXES.charAt((b & 0xF0) >> 4))
            .append(HEXES.charAt((b & 0x0F)));
    }
    return hex.toString();
}
```

Comment: Other methods were running on my 64 byte sample in 5ms, this one runs in 0ms. Probably best for lack of any other String functions like format.

Comment: `if (raw == null) return null` is not fail fast. Why would you ever use a `null` key?

Comment: I suppose it's a habit to input validate. In this case, we prevent any Null reference exception, and leave it up to the caller to handle bad data.

Answer (score 15):

At the minor cost of storing the lookup table this implementation is simple and very fast.

```
 private static final char[] BYTE2HEX=(
    "000102030405060708090A0B0C0D0E0F"+
    "101112131415161718191A1B1C1D1E1F"+
    "202122232425262728292A2B2C2D2E2F"+
    "303132333435363738393A3B3C3D3E3F"+
    "404142434445464748494A4B4C4D4E4F"+
    "505152535455565758595A5B5C5D5E5F"+
    "606162636465666768696A6B6C6D6E6F"+
    "707172737475767778797A7B7C7D7E7F"+
    "808182838485868788898A8B8C8D8E8F"+
    "909192939495969798999A9B9C9D9E9F"+
    "A0A1A2A3A4A5A6A7A8A9AAABACADAEAF"+
    "B0B1B2B3B4B5B6B7B8B9BABBBCBDBEBF"+
    "C0C1C2C3C4C5C6C7C8C9CACBCCCDCECF"+
    "D0D1D2D3D4D5D6D7D8D9DADBDCDDDEDF"+
    "E0E1E2E3E4E5E6E7E8E9EAEBECEDEEEF"+
    "F0F1F2F3F4F5F6F7F8F9FAFBFCFDFEFF").toCharArray();
   ; 

  public static String getHexString(byte[] bytes) {
    final int len=bytes.length;
    final char[] chars=new char[len<<1];
    int hexIndex;
    int idx=0;
    int ofs=0;
    while (ofs<len) {
      hexIndex=(bytes[ofs++] & 0xFF)<<1;
      chars[idx++]=BYTE2HEX[hexIndex++];
      chars[idx++]=BYTE2HEX[hexIndex];
    }
    return new String(chars);
  }
```

Comment: Why not initialize the `BYTE2HEX` array with a simple `for` cycle?

Comment: @icza Is that even possible with a static final (aka constant) field?

Comment: @nevelis It can be assigned in a `static {  }` block.

Comment: @icza because its faster to hardcode a lookup table than to generate it. Here memory complexity is traded with time complexity, ie. needs more memory but faster (every so slightly on both ends)

Answer (score 11):

[**HexFormat**](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/HexFormat.html) was added in **Java 17**:

```
String hex = HexFormat.of().formatHex(array);
```

Answer (score 9):

We don't need to use any external library or to write code based on loops and constants.
Is enough just this:

```
byte[] theValue = .....
String hexaString = new BigInteger(1, theValue).toString(16);
```

Comment: This is **very** similar to everconfusedGuy's Answer.

Comment: Careful you may end up skipping prefix characters in hashes that start with 0's because of how it's first stored as a BigInteger

Answer (score 8):

How about this?

```
    String byteToHex(final byte[] hash)
    {
        Formatter formatter = new Formatter();
        for (byte b : hash)
        {
            formatter.format("%02x", b);
        }
        String result = formatter.toString();
        formatter.close();
        return result;
    }
```

Answer (score 6):

Here's yet another method using Streams:

```
private static String toHexString(byte[] bytes) {
    return IntStream.range(0, bytes.length)
    .mapToObj(i -> String.format("%02X", bytes[i]))
    .collect(Collectors.joining());
}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
public static String toHexString(byte[] bytes) {

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    if (bytes != null) 
        for (byte b:bytes) {

            final String hexString = Integer.toHexString(b & 0xff);

            if(hexString.length()==1)
                sb.append('0');

            sb.append(hexString);//.append(' ');
        }

      return sb.toString();//.toUpperCase();
}
```

To use DatatypeConverter:

```
public String toHexString(byte... bytes) {

    return Optional.ofNullable(bytes)
            .filter(bs->bs.length>0)
            .map(DatatypeConverter::printHexBinary)
            .map(str->IntStream.range(0, str.length())
                    .filter(i->(i%2)==0)        // take every second index
                    .mapToObj(i->"0x" + str.substring(i, i+2))
                    .collect(Collectors.joining(" ")))
            .orElse("");
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Adding a utility jar for simple function is not good option. Instead assemble your own utility classes. following is possible faster implementation.

```
public class ByteHex {

    public static int hexToByte(char ch) {
        if ('0' <= ch && ch <= '9') return ch - '0';
        if ('A' <= ch && ch <= 'F') return ch - 'A' + 10;
        if ('a' <= ch && ch <= 'f') return ch - 'a' + 10;
        return -1;
    }

    private static final String[] byteToHexTable = new String[]
    {
        "00", "01", "02", "03", "04", "05", "06", "07", "08", "09", "0A", "0B", "0C", "0D", "0E", "0F",
        "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "1A", "1B", "1C", "1D", "1E", "1F",
        "20", "21", "22", "23", "24", "25", "26", "27", "28", "29", "2A", "2B", "2C", "2D", "2E", "2F",
        "30", "31", "32", "33", "34", "35", "36", "37", "38", "39", "3A", "3B", "3C", "3D", "3E", "3F",
        "40", "41", "42", "43", "44", "45", "46", "47", "48", "49", "4A", "4B", "4C", "4D", "4E", "4F",
        "50", "51", "52", "53", "54", "55", "56", "57", "58", "59", "5A", "5B", "5C", "5D", "5E", "5F",
        "60", "61", "62", "63", "64", "65", "66", "67", "68", "69", "6A", "6B", "6C", "6D", "6E", "6F",
        "70", "71", "72", "73", "74", "75", "76", "77", "78", "79", "7A", "7B", "7C", "7D", "7E", "7F",
        "80", "81", "82", "83", "84", "85", "86", "87", "88", "89", "8A", "8B", "8C", "8D", "8E", "8F",
        "90", "91", "92", "93", "94", "95", "96", "97", "98", "99", "9A", "9B", "9C", "9D", "9E", "9F",
        "A0", "A1", "A2", "A3", "A4", "A5", "A6", "A7", "A8", "A9", "AA", "AB", "AC", "AD", "AE", "AF",
        "B0", "B1", "B2", "B3", "B4", "B5", "B6", "B7", "B8", "B9", "BA", "BB", "BC", "BD", "BE", "BF",
        "C0", "C1", "C2", "C3", "C4", "C5", "C6", "C7", "C8", "C9", "CA", "CB", "CC", "CD", "CE", "CF",
        "D0", "D1", "D2", "D3", "D4", "D5", "D6", "D7", "D8", "D9", "DA", "DB", "DC", "DD", "DE", "DF",
        "E0", "E1", "E2", "E3", "E4", "E5", "E6", "E7", "E8", "E9", "EA", "EB", "EC", "ED", "EE", "EF",
        "F0", "F1", "F2", "F3", "F4", "F5", "F6", "F7", "F8", "F9", "FA", "FB", "FC", "FD", "FE", "FF"
    };

    private static final String[] byteToHexTableLowerCase = new String[]
    {
        "00", "01", "02", "03", "04", "05", "06", "07", "08", "09", "0a", "0b", "0c", "0d", "0e", "0f",
        "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "1a", "1b", "1c", "1d", "1e", "1f",
        "20", "21", "22", "23", "24", "25", "26", "27", "28", "29", "2a", "2b", "2c", "2d", "2e", "2f",
        "30", "31", "32", "33", "34", "35", "36", "37", "38", "39", "3a", "3b", "3c", "3d", "3e", "3f",
        "40", "41", "42", "43", "44", "45", "46", "47", "48", "49", "4a", "4b", "4c", "4d", "4e", "4f",
        "50", "51", "52", "53", "54", "55", "56", "57", "58", "59", "5a", "5b", "5c", "5d", "5e", "5f",
        "60", "61", "62", "63", "64", "65", "66", "67", "68", "69", "6a", "6b", "6c", "6d", "6e", "6f",
        "70", "71", "72", "73", "74", "75", "76", "77", "78", "79", "7a", "7b", "7c", "7d", "7e", "7f",
        "80", "81", "82", "83", "84", "85", "86", "87", "88", "89", "8a", "8b", "8c", "8d", "8e", "8f",
        "90", "91", "92", "93", "94", "95", "96", "97", "98", "99", "9a", "9b", "9c", "9d", "9e", "9f",
        "a0", "a1", "a2", "a3", "a4", "a5", "a6", "a7", "a8", "a9", "aa", "ab", "ac", "ad", "ae", "af",
        "b0", "b1", "b2", "b3", "b4", "b5", "b6", "b7", "b8", "b9", "ba", "bb", "bc", "bd", "be", "bf",
        "c0", "c1", "c2", "c3", "c4", "c5", "c6", "c7", "c8", "c9", "ca", "cb", "cc", "cd", "ce", "cf",
        "d0", "d1", "d2", "d3", "d4", "d5", "d6", "d7", "d8", "d9", "da", "db", "dc", "dd", "de", "df",
        "e0", "e1", "e2", "e3", "e4", "e5", "e6", "e7", "e8", "e9", "ea", "eb", "ec", "ed", "ee", "ef",
        "f0", "f1", "f2", "f3", "f4", "f5", "f6", "f7", "f8", "f9", "fa", "fb", "fc", "fd", "fe", "ff"
    };

    public static String byteToHex(byte b){
        return byteToHexTable[b & 0xFF];
    }

    public static String byteToHex(byte[] bytes){
        if(bytes == null) return null;
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(bytes.length*2);
        for(byte b : bytes) sb.append(byteToHexTable[b & 0xFF]);
        return sb.toString();
    }

    public static String byteToHex(short[] bytes){
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(bytes.length*2);
        for(short b : bytes) sb.append(byteToHexTable[((byte)b) & 0xFF]);
        return sb.toString();
    }

    public static String byteToHexLowerCase(byte[] bytes){
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(bytes.length*2);
        for(byte b : bytes) sb.append(byteToHexTableLowerCase[b & 0xFF]);
        return sb.toString();
    }

    public static byte[] hexToByte(String hexString) {
        if(hexString == null) return null;
        byte[] byteArray = new byte[hexString.length() / 2];
        for (int i = 0; i < hexString.length(); i += 2) {
            byteArray[i / 2] = (byte) (hexToByte(hexString.charAt(i)) * 16 + hexToByte(hexString.charAt(i+1)));
        }
        return byteArray;
    }

    public static byte hexPairToByte(char ch1, char ch2) {
        return (byte) (hexToByte(ch1) * 16 + hexToByte(ch2));
    }


}
```

Comment: It is never a good choice to write your own "wheel", given there are implementations already available.

Comment: @DonaldDuck I agree with you in most cases. But sometimes adding a dependency  to just use one function is not good either.

Answer (score 2):

Ok so there are a bunch of ways to do this, but if you decide to use a library I would suggest poking about in your project to see if something has been implemented in a library that is already part of your project before adding a new library just to do this.  For example if you don't already have

> org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Hex

maybe you do have...

> org.apache.xerces.impl.dv.util.HexBin

Answer (score 2):

If you're using the Spring Security framework, you can use:

```
import org.springframework.security.crypto.codec.Hex

final String testString = "Test String";
final byte[] byteArray = testString.getBytes();
System.out.println(Hex.encode(byteArray));
```

Answer (score 1):

I usually use the following method for debuf statement, but i don't know if it is the best way of doing it or not

```
private static String digits = "0123456789abcdef";

public static String toHex(byte[] data){
    StringBuffer buf = new StringBuffer();
    for (int i = 0; i != data.length; i++)
    {
        int v = data[i] & 0xff;
        buf.append(digits.charAt(v >> 4));
        buf.append(digits.charAt(v & 0xf));
    }
    return buf.toString();
}
```

Comment: If your debuffer has a bad day, try cluing in StringBuilder instantiation with a number of chars to support: `StringBuilder buf = new StringBuilder(data.length * 2);`.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer to use this:

```
final protected static char[] hexArray = "0123456789ABCDEF".toCharArray();
public static String bytesToHex(byte[] bytes, int offset, int count) {
    char[] hexChars = new char[count * 2];
    for ( int j = 0; j < count; j++ ) {
        int v = bytes[j+offset] & 0xFF;
        hexChars[j * 2] = hexArray[v >>> 4];
        hexChars[j * 2 + 1] = hexArray[v & 0x0F];
    }
    return new String(hexChars);
}
```

It is slightly more flexible adaptation of the accepted answer.
Personally, I keep both the accepted answer and this overload along with it, usable in more contexts.

Comment: The original question was for byte[] to String. Look hex to bytes[] or ask a different question, @NonExistent.

Answer (score 1):

Recently I had to implement a Hex converter to dump the byte stream into the log in Hex format. Initially I did it using `Hex.encodeHex` which has been already discussed in here.

But If you want to represent the byte array in a very presentable/readable way `io.netty.buffer` library could be a great use as it prints out the Hex as well the strings in it eliminating the non-printable characters.

Requirement was something like,

```
0010   56 56 09 35 32 f0 b2 00 50 4c 45 41 53 45 20 52   VV.52...PLEASE R
0020   45 2d 45 4e 54 45 52 20 4c 41 53 54 20 54 52 41   E-ENTER LAST TRA
0030   4e 53 41 43 54 49 4f 4e 00 04                     NSACTION..
```

The shortest way to do the same in a more presentable way using `io.netty.buffer` is

```
import io.netty.buffer.ByteBuf;
import io.netty.buffer.ByteBufUtil;
import io.netty.buffer.Unpooled;

void hexDump(byte[] buf) {
    ByteBuf byteBuf = Unpooled.wrappedBuffer(buf);
    log.trace("Bytes received (Hex)\n" + ByteBufUtil.prettyHexDump(byteBuf.slice()));
}
```

if you are using maven, include the below dependency in the pom.xml (check for the latest version in the netty page)

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.netty</groupId>
    <artifactId>netty-buffer</artifactId>
    <version>4.1.68.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

output was:

```
         +-------------------------------------------------+
         |  0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  a  b  c  d  e  f |
+--------+-------------------------------------------------+----------------+
|00000010| 40 40 b3 f3 80 f3 80 f3 80 f1 48 f1 41 f1 4e f1 |@@........H.A.N.|
|00000020| 47 f1 49 f1 4e f1 47 b5 f1 52 f1 4f f1 43 f1 4b |G.I.N.G..R.O.C.K|
|00000030| f3 80 f3 80 41 b4 40 40 f3 80 f3 80 40 f3 80 04 |....A.@@....@...|
+--------+-------------------------------------------------+----------------+
```

For your reference, the long way (may not be the most efficient) using the discussed methods in the answers is,

```
public static String hexDump(byte[] buf) throws DecoderException
{
    ByteBuffer byteBuf = ByteBuffer.wrap(buf);
    char[] result = Hex.encodeHex(byteBuf);

    String bin = new String(result).toUpperCase();
    String str = new String(Hex.decodeHex(bin), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);

    str = str.replaceAll("[^!-~]", ".");
    StringBuilder out = new StringBuilder();
    int bytes_per_line = 16;

    for (int pos = 0; pos < str.length(); pos += bytes_per_line) {
        out.append(String.format("%04X   ", pos));
        if (2 * (pos + bytes_per_line) >= bin.length()) {
            out.append(String.format("%-" + 2 * bytes_per_line + "s", bin.substring(2 * pos)).replaceAll("..", "$0 "));
        } else {
            out.append(bin.substring(2 * pos, 2 * (pos + bytes_per_line)).replaceAll("..", "$0 "));
        }
        out.append("   ");
        if (pos + bytes_per_line > str.length()) {
            out.append(str.substring(pos));

        } else {
            out.append(str.substring(pos, pos + bytes_per_line));
        }
        out.append("\n");
    }

    return out.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to make it more readable and separate the bytes from each other, you can use the following code in Java 17+:

**Update:** As @BradHards mentioned, it can be simplified.

```
byte[] yourByteArray = { -128, 0, 127 };
// String hexString = new String(HexFormat.ofDelimiter(" ").formatHex(yourByteArray));
String hexString = HexFormat.ofDelimiter(" ").formatHex(yourByteArray);
// 80 00 7f
```

Comment: Why the `new String(..)` constructor? `formatHex` will return a String.

Answer (score 0):

A small variant of the solution proposed by @maybewecouldstealavan, which lets you visually bundle N bytes together in the output hex string:

```java
 final static char[] HEX_ARRAY = "0123456789ABCDEF".toCharArray();
 final static char BUNDLE_SEP = ' ';

public static String bytesToHexString(byte[] bytes, int bundleSize /*[bytes]*/]) {
        char[] hexChars = new char[(bytes.length * 2) + (bytes.length / bundleSize)];
        for (int j = 0, k = 1; j < bytes.length; j++, k++) {
                int v = bytes[j] & 0xFF;
                int start = (j * 2) + j/bundleSize;

                hexChars[start] = HEX_ARRAY[v >>> 4];
                hexChars[start + 1] = HEX_ARRAY[v & 0x0F];

                if ((k % bundleSize) == 0) {
                        hexChars[start + 2] = BUNDLE_SEP;
                }   
        }   
        return new String(hexChars).trim();    
}
```

That is:

```java
bytesToHexString("..DOOM..".toCharArray().getBytes(), 2);
2E2E 444F 4F4D 2E2E

bytesToHexString("..DOOM..".toCharArray().getBytes(), 4);
2E2E444F 4F4D2E2E
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  public static byte[] hexStringToByteArray(String s) {
    int len = s.length();
    byte[] data = new byte[len / 2];
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i += 2) {
      data[i / 2] = (byte) ((Character.digit(s.charAt(i), 16) << 4)
        + Character.digit(s.charAt(i+1), 16));
    }
  return data;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a `java.util.Base64`-like implementation, isn't it pretty?

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Base16/* a.k.a. Hex */ {
    public static class Encoder{
        private static char[] toLowerHex={'0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','a','b','c','d','e','f'};
        private static char[] toUpperHex={'0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','A','B','C','D','E','F'};
        private boolean upper;
        public Encoder(boolean upper) {
            this.upper=upper;
        }
        public String encode(byte[] data){
            char[] value=new char[data.length*2];
            char[] toHex=upper?toUpperHex:toLowerHex;
            for(int i=0,j=0; i<data.length; i++){
                int octet=data[i]&0xFF;
                value[j++]=toHex[octet>>4];
                value[j++]=toHex[octet&0xF];
            }
            return new String(value);
        }
        static final Encoder LOWER_CASE=new Encoder(false);
        static final Encoder UPPER_CASE=new Encoder(true);
    }
    public static Encoder getEncoder(){
        return Encoder.LOWER_CASE;
    }
    public static Encoder getUpperEncoder(){
        return Encoder.UPPER_CASE;
    }

    public static class Decoder{
      private static int maxIndex=102;
      private static int[] toIndex;
      static {
        toIndex=new int[maxIndex+1];
        Arrays.fill(toIndex, -1);
        char[] chars={'0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','A','B','C','D','E','F','a','b','c','d','e','f'};
        for(int i=0; i<chars.length; i++) {
          toIndex[(int)chars[i]]=i;
        }
      }
      public Decoder() {
      }
      public byte[] decode(String str) {
          char[] value=str.toCharArray();
          int start=0;
          if(value.length>2 && value[0]=='0' && (value[1]=='x' || value[1]=='X')) {
            start=2;
          }
          int byteLength=(value.length-start)/2; // ignore trailing odd char if exists
          byte[] data=new byte[byteLength];
          for(int i=start,j=0;i<value.length;i+=2,j++){
              int i1;
              int i2;
              char c1=value[i];
              char c2=value[i+1];
              if(c1>maxIndex || (i1=toIndex[(int)c1])<0 || c2>maxIndex || (i2=toIndex[(int)c2])<0) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid character at "+i);
              }
              data[j]=(byte)((i1<<4)+i2);
          }
          return data;
      }
      static final Decoder IGNORE_CASE=new Decoder();
  }
  public static Decoder getDecoder(){
      return Decoder.IGNORE_CASE;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private static String bytesToHexString(byte[] bytes, int length) {
        if (bytes == null || length == 0) return null;

        StringBuilder ret = new StringBuilder(2*length);

        for (int i = 0 ; i < length ; i++) {
            int b;

            b = 0x0f & (bytes[i] >> 4);
            ret.append("0123456789abcdef".charAt(b));

            b = 0x0f & bytes[i];
            ret.append("0123456789abcdef".charAt(b));
        }

        return ret.toString();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Can't find any solution on this page that doesn't

1. Use a loop
2. Use javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter which compiles fine but often throws java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError at runtime.

Here's a solution which doesn't have the flaws above(no promises mine doesn't have other flaws though)

```
import java.math.BigInteger;

import static java.lang.System.out;
public final class App2 {
    // | proposed solution.
    public static String encode(byte[] bytes) {          
        final int length = bytes.length;

        // | BigInteger constructor throws if it is given an empty array.
        if (length == 0) {
            return "00";
        }

        final int evenLength = (int)(2 * Math.ceil(length / 2.0));
        final String format = "%0" + evenLength + "x";         
        final String result = String.format (format, new BigInteger(bytes));

        return result;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        // 00
        out.println(encode(new byte[] {})); 

        // 01
        out.println(encode(new byte[] {1})); 

        //203040
        out.println(encode(new byte[] {0x20, 0x30, 0x40})); 

        // 416c6c20796f75722062617365206172652062656c6f6e6720746f2075732e
        out.println(encode("All your base are belong to us.".getBytes()));
    }
}
```

I couldn't get this under 62 opcodes, but if you can live without 0 padding in case the first byte is less than 0x10, then the following solution only uses 23 opcodes. Really shows how "easy to implement yourself" solutions like "pad with a zero if string length is odd" can get pretty expensive if a native implementation is not already available(or in this case, if BigInteger had an option to prefix with zeros in toString).

```
public static String encode(byte[] bytes) {          
    final int length = bytes.length;

    // | BigInteger constructor throws if it is given an empty array.
    if (length == 0) {
        return "00";
    }

    return new BigInteger(bytes).toString(16);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution is based on maybeWeCouldStealAVan's solution, but does not rely on any additionaly allocated lookup tables. It does not uses any 'int-to-char' casts hacks (actually, `Character.forDigit()` does it, performing some comparison to check what the digit truly is) and thus might be a bit slower. Please feel free to use it wherever you want. Cheers.

```
public static String bytesToHex(final byte[] bytes)
{
    final int numBytes = bytes.length;
    final char[] container = new char[numBytes * 2];

    for (int i = 0; i < numBytes; i++)
    {
        final int b = bytes[i] & 0xFF;

        container[i * 2] = Character.forDigit(b >>> 4, 0x10);
        container[i * 2 + 1] = Character.forDigit(b & 0xF, 0x10);
    }

    return new String(container);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Converts bytes data to hex characters

@param bytes byte array to be converted to hex string
@return byte String in hex format

private static String bytesToHex(byte[] bytes) {
    char[] hexChars = new char[bytes.length * 2];
    int v;
    for (int j = 0; j < bytes.length; j++) {
        v = bytes[j] & 0xFF;
        hexChars[j * 2] = HEX_ARRAY[v >>> 4];
        hexChars[j * 2 + 1] = HEX_ARRAY[v & 0x0F];
    }
    return new String(hexChars);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If you're looking for a byte array exactly like this for python, I have converted this Java implementation into python.

```
class ByteArray:

@classmethod
def char(cls, args=[]):
    cls.hexArray = "0123456789ABCDEF".encode('utf-16')
    j = 0
    length = (cls.hexArray)

    if j < length:
        v = j & 0xFF
        hexChars = [None, None]
        hexChars[j * 2] = str( cls.hexArray) + str(v)
        hexChars[j * 2 + 1] = str(cls.hexArray) + str(v) + str(0x0F)
        # Use if you want...
        #hexChars.pop()

    return str(hexChars)

array = ByteArray()
print array.char(args=[])
```

Answer (score -2):

// Shifting bytes is more efficient
// You can use this one too

```
public static String getHexString (String s) 
{
    byte[] buf = s.getBytes();

    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();

    for (byte b:buf)
    {
        sb.append(String.format("%x", b));
    }


        return sb.toString();
}
```

Comment: Be aware that this approach produces single character values for bytes 0 to 15 (i.e. 0..F).
The expectation would probably be getting 2 character values 00 .. 0F.
At least converting back from hex to bytes[] won't work.

Comment: You should replace `"%x"` by `"%02x"` as @Boomer pointed out

Answer (score -3):

Just iterate over all bytes, convert them to a hex String using `Integer.toString` (Unfortunately, there is no `Byte.toString` with a radix parameter) and append them all to a `StringBuilder`.

```java
byte[] arr;//set it to your value
StringBuilder sb=new StringBuilder(arr.length*2);//1 byte...2 hex digits
for(int i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
  sb.append(Integer.toString(arr[i],16));
}
String hexValue=sb.toString();
```

This is similar to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13006907/10871900) from [Pointer Null](https://stackoverflow.com/users/907695/pointer-null) but it uses `Integer.toString` instead of `String.format` improving the performance.

Comment: This is wrong.  The above does not take into account that the `Integer.toString(x,16)` method does not left-pad with `0`.  Most people would probably expect that a String with value `A\nB` would be represented as `410a42` in hex. However the presented solution will give `41a42`. Ouch!